# jquery isotope - firing layoutComplete callback only on initial load

Tags: jquery-isotope

I am using the [Isotope Plugin](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/). I need to wait until the document has settled on a fixed height before firing a scroll method. This means I need to wait until Isotope has finished doing its thing. I have two calls to Isotope; once on the intial document load, and again to bind it to a click handler. I have got the callback to work.. but only on the click handler. However I need to bind it to the initial load, NOT the click-handler.

Here is my code:

```
var active          = $(".tour-filter li a").first();
var defaultFilter   = active.data('filter');

active.addClass('active');

    var container = $('.tour-list');
    container.isotope({
        filter: defaultFilter,   // I need to bind the 'layoutComplete' callback HERE, so it only fires once on the page load
        layoutMode: 'fitRows'
    });

container.isotope( 'on', 'layoutComplete', function (isoInstance, laidOutItems){
    alert('done!');
});

    $('.tour-filter a').click(function(){
        $('.tour-filter .active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');

        var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');

        container.isotope({
            filter: selector,      // ...But it is binding itself here?
            layoutMode: 'fitRows'
         });
         return false;
    });
```

I am using Isotope version v2.1.0.

Comment: A jsfiddle or a link? What is the html for your filters?

Answer (score 0):

I've just got the same problem here.

So if anyone like to know how I've done this, take a look.

```
var jGrid =  jQuery('.grid');

//callback function
var initTiles = function initTiles (obj, objArray)
{
    console.log(obj, objArray);
};

jGrid.isotope(
{
    itemSelector: '.tile',

    //disable layout on initialization
    isInitLayout: false,

    masonry:
    {
        columnWidth: 218,
        isFitWidth: true,
        gutter: 2
    }
});

//wait for the layoutComplete event
jGrid.isotope('on', 'layoutComplete', function (objArray)
{
    //callback ...
    for(var i = 0; i < objArray.length; i++)
    {
        var obj = objArray[i];

        initTiles(obj, objArray);
    }
});

//trigger the layout method to trigger layoutComplete
jGrid.isotope('layout');
```